# Solving square root recurrences

Tags: algorithms

How can I solve that recurrence a square root?

[image]

Comment: It looks like your picture is cut off on the left

Comment: Hi, It is the big theta notation

Comment: If we can't see the whole problem, we can't answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the domain on $n$ nor the base case, I made some assumptions about the recurrence. Let $a$ represent the base case for the recurrence such that $$T(n)=\begin{cases} 
a,&n\leq 1\\
4T\left(n/2\right)+n^2\sqrt{n},&n>1
\end{cases},$$
where $n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Unfolding the recurrence gives us
$$
\begin{align}
T(n)&=4T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n^2\sqrt{n}\\
&=4\left(4T\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right)+n^2\sqrt{n}\\
&=4\left(4\left(4T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right)+\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2\sqrt{\frac{n}{4}}\right)+\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}\right)+n^2\sqrt{n}\\
&\ldots\\
&=4^{p}T(1)+4^{p-1}f(x_{p-1})+\dots+4^2f(x_2)+4f(x_1)+f(x_0),
\end{align}
$$
where $p$ represents the number of times that $n$ is halved in order to reach $1$, $f(x)=x^2\sqrt{x}$ represents the constant term of $T(x)$, and $x_k=n/2^k$. In other words, the expanded recurrence will have $p+1$ terms (one for each nested recurrence, plus the constant term). Notice that $f(x_p)\approx 1$ since $p$ represents the number of times that we must recur to get to $1$, and $f(1)=1$. The number of times that $n$ is halved is the solution to $$\frac{n}{2^x}=1\implies n=2^x\implies x=\log_2(n),$$ meaning $p=\left\lceil\log_2(n)\right\rceil$.

Rewriting $T(n)$ as a summation, we get
$$
\begin{align}
 &\;4^pT(1)+\sum^{p-1}_{i=0}4^if(x_i)\\
=&\;4^pT(1)+\sum^{p-1}_{i=0}\left(4^i \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)^2\sqrt{\frac{n}{2^i}}\right)\\
=&\;4^pT(1)+\sum^{p-1}_{i=0}4^i \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)^{5/2}\\
=&\;4^pT(1)+\sum^{p-1}_{i=0}\frac{2^{2i}n^{5/2}}{2^{5i/2}}\\
=&\;4^pT(1)+n^{5/2}\sum^{p-1}_{i=0}2^{-i/2}.\\
\end{align}
$$
Or, alternatively $$T(n)=4^pT(1)+n^{5/2}\sum^{p-1}_{i=0}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^i,$$
which is just a geometric series. So $T(n)$ can be written in closed form as
$$T(n)=4^pT(1)+n^{5/2}\left(\frac{2^{1-p/2}-2}{\sqrt{2}-2}\right).$$